# .htaccess rules being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have the below in a `.htaccess` file. The SSL redirect is working perfectly, however when I got to `abc.html` I get a 404. The `test.html` page exists and works if I go directly to it.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^abc\.html$ /test.html [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Rewrite rules were all working as expected with a much longer list of rules previously. After updating the primary domain in cPanel they stopped working and have reduced it down to this minimal example.

Comment: What is the complete url to the abc.html file?

Comment: It's an internal DNS record but in this example it would be `https://example.org/abc.html` and the test file is at `https://example.org/test.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears there was a configuration error in the `httpd.conf` generated by cPanel when the domain was updated. Forcing cPanel to regenerate the conf files fixed the issue.